# Angular2 component rendering a template with data received without saving it locally in a property?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a service which GETs data from some API and a pair of components each calling this service on init to set properties with a copy of the data.

I also want this service to start caching data in memory to stop unnecessary calls to the server whenever data is requested.

This would mean I'd have several copies of the same data (in each component and in cache).

Is there a way to fetch data for rendering a component and then throw the data away, not keeping it in a component's property?

Comment: No. You would have several references to the same data. A reference costs nothing.

Comment: You are right, it is an actual reference, not even a copy-on-write. Thanks!